# Revert server to past commit with bare repository hooks

Tags: git, githooks, git-bare

I have a server with a bare git repository that I push to for live deployment. It has a simple `post-receive` hook that updates my server code with the latest on `master`.

I sometimes need to revert to a specific past commit when bugs are found on the production server (I test myself locally, but I don't catch everything). Is there a nice* way to revert to a past commit with this setup?

*By nice I mean a one-liner like pushing to the bare repository: `git push prod master`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to keep your *mistake* in the history, this will add commits which compensate the commits you specify. (master must be checked out locally) For example, if you want to revert the last commit, you can use:

```
git revert master
git push origin master
```

If you want to remove the last 2 commits from history (master must be checked out locally):

```
git reset master~2
git push -f origin master
```

Or without changing anything local, this should work as well:

```
git push -f origin master~2:master
```

The last two will force-update the master to the third from last `master` commit. Which is problematic if someone else already pulled the commits you are removing.

Comment: Will there be any problem i I ask whoever has pulled the commit to reset their local branch too?

Comment: @UgaBuga: No that's no problem, if you communicate it to others and they perform for example a `git reset --hard origin/master` on their local `master` branch after a `git fetch`. However, this will discard their local commits and index. If they have local commits they want to keep after a forced update, they should rebase them on the updated branch.